# Appending elements to an array instance variable and print out - Python

Tags: python, arrays, append, instance-variables

I am trying to read in a file and extract the records and print the file in a class. The error I get is that the object does not have a function append? I have declared it as a array, but it does not appear to recognize it. Any hints what the issue is about? Is this a valid approach to the problem?

```
import os 

class URL():
    Test=[]
    def read(self,file):
        for l in open(file):
            fields=l.split(',')
            company=fields[1].replace(" ",'+')
            adress="+".join((str(fields[5]),str(fields[11]) ) )
            self.Test.append( "".join(("http://www.someurl/market-search?q=",company)))
    def Print(self):
        for i in Test:
            return i 

ROOT = os.getcwd()
START_URL=URL()
START_URL.read(ROOT+'\Company_Lists\Test_of_company.csv')

print START_URL.Print
```

Comment: Could you please give the exact error you get ?

Comment: self.Test != Test. You haven't defined self.Test

Comment: self.Test.append("".join(("http://www.someurl/marker-search?=company))) AttributeError 'function' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @M4rtini, you are correct, but here since ```Print()``` doesn't write to ```Test```, it will inherit ```Test``` from ```URL```.  It will work, but it's definitely bad form

Comment: @wnnmaw The error is most probably in the read function, where he tries to use `self.Test` not in the print function.

Comment: @AxelEricsson, I think you would be better off replacing ```for l in open(file):``` with ```with open(file) as f:``` followed by ```for l in f:```

Comment: I would not build a path like this: `START_URL.read(ROOT+'\Company_Lists\Test_of_company.csv')` Instead, I'd write: `import os.path;
p = os.path.join([ROOT, 'Company_Lists', 'Test_of_company.csv']);
START_URL.read(p)`

Comment: And then just call `Print` like this: `START_URL.Print()`.

Comment: And rewrite `Print` as: `for i in self.Test: print i`

Comment: @M4rtini, I agree, but when he declares ```Test = []``` on the top level of the class that should make ```Test``` a class attribute so referring to it as ```self.Test``` in ```read()``` makes sense

Comment: @wnnmaw is that the case for all python versions? The error message he gave here, points to that not being the case when he ran his code.

Comment: @M4rtini, ooh good point, I only tested on 2.7.6, not sure about older versions or 3.x

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite this:

```
import os 
import os.path


class URL(object):
    Test = []
    def read(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                fields = line.split(',')
                company = fields[1].replace(" ", '+')
                self.Test.append("http://www.someurl/market-search?q={0}".format(company))

    def print(self):
        for i in self.Test:
            print i 


def main():
    root = os.getcwd()
    start_url = URL()
    p = os.path.join(root, 'Company_Lists', 'Test_of_company.csv')
    start_url.read(p)
    start_url.print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This script works with two small changes, the print needs to be Print otherwise it tries to call the print function. I need to remove the [] from the os.join.path, since open() cannot take a list as an argument. I keep getting amazed by stackoverflow community! Thanks a ton. Your string manipulation was a lot nicer than mine :).

Comment: Wow, can't use `print` as name of method? Surprising.

Comment: Thanks for that constructive comment, you are the best hughdbrown.